# InDesign and advert size (PDFs)

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've learnt the basics of InDesign and created a 10-page magazine with some adverts in (stored as PDFs). My earlier question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/creating-a-book-using-indesign-new-to-this) was from a purely educational standpoint; not an actual printed magazine, for clarification purposes. (Apologies for not clarifying this last time)

The version I am using is InDesign CS5.

The magazine is 200 mm x 270 mm (200 mm width x 270 mm height) and I have adverts in 193 x 270 mm (all dimensions quoted here are width x height), 193 x 130mm and 93 x 270mm in size (stored as PDFs created from InDesign).

This magazine is only for educational use; I am not actually printing a proper magazine *yet*.

My question is, what's the basic standards for inserting adverts into InDesign (I know how to do it using the Place function of InDesign) - do you insert them in at the size the PDF was (193 x 270 mm advert for example) or would you rescale / resize them? What do you tend to do?

I did look up on Google, but that was information on how to do it, which was useful for me.

However, what I'm wondering is, if this was an actual production magazine, how would I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In actual production all advertising spaces have specified dimensions - full page, half page, third page, quarter page, eighth page, etc. Those dimensions are posted online or provided in a specification sheet to advertisers. Specifications would include trim size, bleed size, and any other restrictions. Advertisers provide artwork for their own ad at the size they wish to pay for.

Advertising art from clients would match the predetermined sizes and simply be dropped into place. If artwork received did not match the specified sizes the art would either be kicked back to be sized properly or in **exceptionally rare** cases production may alter the artwork size if it's merely a scale issue.

In general, if a magazine received artwork at an incorrect size it's sent back to the client rather than risk any issue with production altering what the client is paying for.

If the client wants the magazine to produce advertising artwork, prices are adjusted accordingly. However, most publications will either shy away from creating the ad artwork or they have a dedicated department for ad creation. Ad creation is a whole mess of issue unto itself and not something the publication production team generally has time to deal with.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very helpful to me and it's something I didn't know beforehand.